# Azure pythonsdk to fetch list of blobs in ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-python-sdk

I am fetching the list of blob store using python sdk from Classic Azure Blob Store

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

...
def __init__ (self, key, blob_accnt_name):
    self._blob_acct_url = f'https://{blob_accnt_name}.blob.core.windows.net'
    self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=self._blob_acct_url, credential=key)
    self.container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(azure_blob_storage.get_container())
    
def fetchBlob(self):
    blob_items = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='{}'.format(blob_path)) ############# (1)
    blob_paths =[]
    if any(True for _ in blob_items):
           blob_paths.append(....
...
```

For the ADLS Gen2, i am trying to fetch using the file_system_client, `get_paths`

```py
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings

# function to initialize the ADLS  account
def initStorage(storage_account_name, storage_account_key):
    try:  
        global service_client
        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# Function to list the contents of the directory
def listDirectoryContents():
    try:
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="<container-name>") # system name is container name in ADLS g2
        paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path="<directory-name>")  ################ (2)

        for path in paths:
            print(path.name + '\n')

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Is `container_client.list_blobs` and the `file_system_client.get_paths` are the same usage? (refer the code snippet lines marked as - #######(1) and #########(2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Well, the function used in both the cases i.e., `list_blobs` and `get_paths` will give a generator which will lazily follow the tokens.
- But the generator itself contain different things in case of  `list_blobs`  as the name suggest it will contain blobs which are inside the container while for `get_paths` it will be paths for files in the file system.
- The classes are also different in the sense that they are applicable to containers and file system respectively but theoretically they do same thing i.e., they let us interact with entities which may not yet exist.

[container client class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python)

[file system client class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.filesystemclient?view=azure-python)